# CMake Error could not find a configuration file for package "SDL2" that is compatible

Tags: c++, cmake

When I run `cmake ..` I receive the following error:

```
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:20 (find_package):
  Could not find a configuration file for package "SDL2" that is compatible
  with requested version "".

  The following configuration files were considered but not accepted:

    C:/Users/Miguel/Documents/vcpkg/installed/x64-windows/share/sdl2/SDL2Config.cmake, version: 2.0.16 (64bit)



-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
```

I don't know which version should I install because it doesn't give me any requested version

Also, the code isn´t mine its from https://github.com/AlexAltea/orbital/

Comment: It is not version which is not accepted. It is `64bit` which is not accepted, because (it seems) you build the project for 32-bit.